# Likelihood Matrix from a Random Forest?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, random-forest, likelihood, sequence-analysis

I'm going through the supporting material of a paper (https://science.sciencemag.org/content/360/6384/81) , trying to reproduce their results (see below, note that HVG=highly variable gene). The data this methodology is being applied to is a matrix of single cell sequencing gene expression data. We're talking ~1100 genes and ~760 cells. The idea is to classify cells based on the gene expression. I'm struggling to properly understand their use of a random forest model in step 3.

They refine the features under consideration in step 2, and presumably use the tentative identities in 1 as training data for randomForest(). I understand that they can then use this model to predict further data, but get confused when they start talking about forming a likelihood matrix.

So let my question be the following: How can you begin with a random forest model and extract a 'likelihood matrix' to judge classification. What is this intended to mean? I feel I must be misunderstanding, so any insight would be much appreciated.

(In addition, if you understand how they are applying hierarchical clustering that would also be great. I can't quite work out if they're clustering the cells or the genes, and where the identifiers come in)

[image]

Comment: Who are "they"? You should be stating your question **here** in your own words. You should not be phrasing your question using words of other men.

Comment: If you do not get a solution here you might try an R mailing list where you might find people who know about applying random forests to genetic data

Comment: (+1) I do not understand what a "likelihood matrix" is in regards to random forests standard literature. I quickly looked for random forests references in the paper and in the supplementary material and only Breiman (2001) is mentioned - it doesn't have anything "likelihood related". Maybe some scavenging on some of the references in the supplementary material gets more info. @mdewey: which R list you refer at? They are a few! 

Comment: Nor do I understand what they mean by likelihood matrices in this sense, thank you for the helpful reply.

Comment: To stans, I'm sorry my phrasing offended you. But I'd thank you not to refer to 'other men' as you put it. Both myself, and the author I'm in contact with are female.

Comment: Briefly revisiting this: Maybe the authors refer to the use of "Proximity Plots" as these are defined in Hastie et al. (2009) Chapt. 15.3.3 but that's a hunch.